# How to combine RxDB and MobX

Tags: reactjs, electron, mobx

I started out with an electron + react + mobx setup and now want to add RxDB to the mix. I thought that I could maybe just handle rxdb stuff (inserts / subscriptions) inside the store but I don't really know how.

Basically my question is:

How can I sync my Mobx store and my RxDB?

Code currently is roughly like this:

```
class RecordingStore {
     ...
     constructor() {
        database.getDatabase( 'mydb', 'idb').then(async(db) => {
            this.db = db
            await db.recordings.sync({
                remote: syncURL,
                direction: {
                    pull: true,
                    push: true
                }
            });
        }
     }

     @action addRecording(title) {
        const item = new Recording(title)
        // should I really keep two collections? (RxDb AND Mobx)
        this.recordings.push(item)
        this.db.recordings.insert({ title: title }).then(()=>{console.log("recording saved")})
        return item
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can deduce, rxdb is merely an rxjs observable instance of PouchDB!

If you are using Mobx, then you can safely skip the rxjs step and use PouchDB directly; else code the easy way and use the [mobx-pouchbd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-pouchdb) dependency and..:

```
save() {
    if (super.save()) {
        POUCH_DB_INSTANCE.put(this.toJS());
    }
}
```